# How to count data use relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Table `user` example :

```
id | name | status | first_name | last_name | create_at
```

Table `post` example :

```
id | title | name | description | user_id | status | create_at
```

In `model user`:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

In `model post`:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
}
```

In the post table database, there is a `status` column with three values ​​of 1, 2, 3, now I want to count how many status = 1, and how many `status = 2, 3`

I have two ways to handle that is to use a relationship or call the post model to handle it
In `UserController.php`:

```
// The best way to try is relationship
    $user = User::select(['id', 'name'])
              ->with(['posts:user_id'])
              ->where('type', 2)
              ->get();
```

Or:

```
$user = User::select(['id', 'name'])
          ->where('type', 2)
          ->get();
    foreach ($user as $val) {
      $statusPublic[] = Posts::where('user_id', $val['id'])->where('status', '=', 1)->count();
      $statusPrivate[] = Posts::where('user_id', $val['id'])->whereIn('status', [2, 3])->count();
    }
```

My problem is that in the posts table it has 300,000 items . If you handle the status count like that, it's very slow. Sometimes up to 20s. Is there any way to improve? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get count per user?

Comment: You need to make indexing your column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

In model user

```
public function posts_status_one()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('status', '=', 1);
}

public function posts_status_other()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->whereIn('status', [2, 3]);
}
```

Now in your query

```
$user = User::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->withCount(['posts_status_one', 'posts_status_other'])
    ->where('type', 2)
    ->get();
```

By using withCount the n + 1 query, will reduce to 3 query.

Comment: Thank you, Your way is very good. But I don't know why I already indexed the status, but when you do it your way. Its processing time is 15 seconds?

Comment: My table structure, same as on my question..First part

Comment: try to add composite index on user id and status.

Comment: In the user table I have indexed for the column type, id . Post table I index column status

Comment: in your post table give composite index like `$table->index(['user_id', 'status'])`

Comment: And one more thing you need to use the pagination. To reduce the query timing.

Comment: Use pagination.? Can you tell me more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `whereHas()` method

```php
User::where('type', 2)->whereHas('posts', function($q) {
    $q->where('status', '=', 1);
})->count();
```

Comment: I tried your way, But it takes 9 seconds to process. What did I do?

Comment: @miedkes make index of your status column

Comment: @sta Thank you. I have indexed the status column. But once it runs it takes 9 seconds or more. I don't know where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Miedkes You may have problem with server, how you sure it is because of code? you should use `microtime(true)` before and after the query